# Application pool recycling — doesn't recover

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, iis-10

I have an ASP.NET Core app — a RESTful API with websocket functionality through SignalR.

We have an issue when the application pool is recycled automatically every 29 hours - sometimes (rarely) it doesn't recover. Even manually, I can't restart the application pool.

Yesterday the only thing that helped was restarting the w3 publishing service.

By looking through logs I can see one moment the server responds nicely and fast with code 200 responses, then next it's all code 400 responses (?) and shortly thereafter 503.

Any idea what could be preventing it from recycling. The event log states in order:

---

A worker process with process id of '29752' serving application pool 'DefaultAppPool' has requested a recycle because the worker process reached its allowed processing time limit.

---

A worker process '29752' serving application pool 'DefaultAppPool' failed to stop a listener channel for protocol 'http' in the allotted time.  The data field contains the error number.

Binary data:
In Words
0000: 800705B4

---

A process serving application pool 'DefaultAppPool' exceeded time limits during shut down. The process id was '29752'.

Comment: Which version of ASP.NET Core? 2.2? 2.1? other?

Comment: Is it an IIS in-process web application or an IIS out-of-process web application? ([See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#iis-options))

Comment: It's an in-process ASP.NET Core 2.1 app.

Comment: ASP.NET Core 2.1 does not support IIS in-process.